# JavaScript: Not Calling Constructor Function

Tags: javascript

Can someone shed some light as to why this doesn't work the way I think it should (or what I'm overlooking).

```
function Pane(data) {
    var state = {
        show: function(data) {
            var pane = document.querySelector('.pane[data-content='+data.target+']');
            pane.classList.add('active');
        },
        hide: function(data) {
            var pane = document.querySelector('.pane[data-content='+data.target+']');
            var paneSibling = $(pane.parentNode.childNodes);
            paneSibling.each(function(sibling) {
                if(check.isElement(sibling)) {
                    var isActive = sibling.classList.contains('active');
                    if(sibling != pane && isActive) {
                        sibling.classList.remove('active');
                    };
                };
            });
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

So I can console log `Pane(arg).show/hide` and it'll log it as a function, so why is it when I call `Pane(arg).show` it doesn't do anything? The functions in the object work (outside of the constructor function in their own functions).

Comment: looks like you always return the whole state object, wich wont execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is returning the `state` object, so it will never return the constructed object, even when used with `new`. Since `state` contains those methods, you can just call the function and immediately invoke one of the methods on the returned object.

Now, if you're expecting `show` and `hide` to automatically have access to `data` via closure, it's not working because you're shadowing the variable by declaring the method parameters. You can do this instead:

```
function Pane(data) {
    var state = {
        show: function() {
            var data = data || arguments[0];
            var pane = document.querySelector('.pane[data-content='+data.target+']');
            pane.classList.add('active');
        },
        hide: function() {
            var data = data || arguments[0];
            var pane = document.querySelector('.pane[data-content='+data.target+']');
            var paneSibling = $(pane.parentNode.childNodes);
            paneSibling.each(function(sibling) {
                if(check.isElement(sibling)) {
                    var isActive = sibling.classList.contains('active');
                    if(sibling != pane && isActive) {
                        sibling.classList.remove('active');
                    };
                };
            });
        }
    }
    return state;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Pane({}).show();
```

Or like this:

```
var p = Pane();
p.show();
```

Or force a new argument when needed:

```
p.show({foo:'bar'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding the original argument in each function.
So what you are doing is to find elements with the attribute `data-content='undefined'`

This obviously doesn't work.

So to fix this you should just remove the data argument in the show/hide function.

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B6PdJ0P1Fk4FWcO4GXS5?p=preview) showing the problem and fix.